# SSD disappears/shuts down while computer is running

Tags: linux, ssd, defective-hardware

so this is the first time I'm having a problem with a SSD.

**Issue**: While the computer is running - and has been for at least one hour - one of my SSDs suddenly 'disappears' for lack of a better word. System can't find anymore/can't access it. If I reboot the system BIOS will not find/list that SSD either. Same for shutting down the computer and starting it after that.

**Workaround**: The only thing that helps is shutting down the computer, removing power from the power supply, pressing the power button a few times - I think that discharges some capacitators? - reconnecting the power supply and starting again.

This has been happening since two months now for about 5 times in total. I changed the power cable of the SSD already but that didn't seem to fix it.

The SSD is warm to the touch but not hot so I don't think it's a temperature issue.

The SSD in question has been in use for 18 months now and 16 months when the issue first presented.

The SSD is a Samsung 750 EVO MZ-750250BW 250GB.

My question would be if anyone has seen this issue before and/or knows how or if it can be fixed?

Comment: Any SMART alert data on the SSD? Download Piriform Speccy, then go to Storage and find your SSD from the list of drives and drill down into the S.M.A.R.T. data.

Comment: @spikey_richie I used [gsmartcontrol](https://gsmartcontrol.sourceforge.io/home/) which is a frontend for `smartctl`. I ran an Extended/Long test and it came back with no issues. As far as I could tell all values were well in their ranges. I will repeat that test tonight.

Comment: You say you changed the power cable. Have you also changed the data cable? P.S. Sorry, I missed the *nix tag. Assumed it was Windows.

Comment: @spikey_richie not yet, will do that during the weekend. I'm also ordering a new SSD to do proper cross checks. As for your P.S. that's fine, happens ;)

Comment: Might also be worth trying a different SATA header on your mobo, or a different molex output on your PSU.

Comment: Okay, switched cables and SATA slot on motherboard. Same thing happened again but this time after ~10 minutes of running. I had started a complete copy of everything that is on that harddisk. I applied my 'workaround' again and it worked fine after that. Managed to get all data off it. SMART still doesn't see anything wrong, so I guess it's the chip/controller of the harddisk.

Comment: @spikey_richie I replaced the SSD with a new one. Connected to the same SATA port. No issues yet.